# How can I edit the Woocommerce product widget html class?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I would like to add a class to the existing woocommerce product widget.

The file `'/includes/widgets/class-wc-widget-products.php'` has the following filter.

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_before_widget_product_list', '<ul class="product_list_widget">' );
```

Is there a method that I can edit the html `<ul class="product_list_widget">` in that filter within my theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the given filter to change the html.

Use this in your themes `functions.php` file

```
function wpse240457_add_class($html) {
  $html = '<ul class="product_list_widget your-new-class">';
  return $html;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_before_widget_product_list', 'wpse240457_add_class', 1, 15);
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks! I had no idea that add_filter is used to modify existing :)